# Adding NSTableView to NSView Programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nstableviewcell, nstablecolumn

I am having a bit of trouble adding a NSTableView to an NSView programatically. The view is the first view of an NSSplitView. My Pointers are set up right i am sure of it because I can add a NSButton to the view no problem. Also my tableview's delegate and datasource methods are working as expected. If I use interface builder to add the table view to my view it works. However, I dont want to use IB. I would like to be able to do this through code. Here is the code I am currently using.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{


    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"March",@"April",@"May", nil];


    tableView = [[NSTableView alloc]initWithFrame:firstView.frame];



    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];



    [firstView addSubview:tableView];

    NSButton *j = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:firstView.frame];
    [j setTitle:@"help"];

    [firstView addSubview:j];




}
```

The NSButton object appears on screen although if I comment out the button the tableview does not appear. What am I doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: is tableView a property, and if so, is it declared as strong (or retain)?

Comment: The tableview is a property declared as @property (nonatomic, retain) NSTableView *tableView;.

Comment: I have ARC turned off for this project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you, from your help I was able to figure this out. IB automatically inserts the NSScrollview around the table view and it also inserts a column for you. In order to do it this from code you need to allocate a scroll view and a column. Here is what I am currently utilizing if anyone else comes across this problem.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{

    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"March",@"April",@"May", nil];

    NSScrollView * tableContainer = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:firstView.bounds];

    //This allows the view to be resized by the view holding it 
    [tableContainer setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];

    tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableContainer.frame];
    [tableView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
    NSTableColumn *column =[[NSTableColumn alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"1"];
    [column.headerCell setTitle:@"Header Title"];


    [tableView addTableColumn:column];



    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];


    [tableContainer setDocumentView:tableView];

    [firstView addSubview:tableContainer];

    //You mentioned that ARC is turned off so You need to release these:
    [tableView release];
    [tableContainer release];
    [column release];


}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`NSTableView` by default is in `NSScrollView`. So You can do it like this:

```
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"March",@"April",@"May", nil];

NSScrollView * tableContainer = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:firstView.frame];
tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:firstView.frame];

[tableView setDataSource:self];
[tableView setDelegate:self];

[tableContainer setDocumentView:tableView];

[firstView addSubview:tableContainer];

//You mentioned that ARC is turned off so You need to release these:
[tableView release];
[tableContainer release];
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer this works. can you explain why if the table view by default is incapsulated by a scroll view why is not the table view alloc init method enough and do I have to create the columns and rows as well or are they generated for me.

Comment: @xitzxmythicx You need to create everything it just creates empty `NSTableView` in `NSScrollView`.